My react native project returns a blank page
I have successfully initialized a react native project using expo coo and I get a webpage rendering with the '.....edit your app.js....'. When I add other screens and modify app.he as required I get a blank screen. No error on terminal. The web bundling notification is in green text. What could be the issue?
I created other screens and edited app.js to import those screens. When I invoked npx expo start --clear, I get a blank page. I expected a start screen with login and registration buttons.

Try to start server again with -c flag if that not work
Delete node_module and .expo then reinstall by npm i or yarn install then run server again it might solved the issue .

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
